# Creating an output based off multiple values from different columns

Tags: sql

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| policy1 | 9999 |
| policy2 | 9999 |
| policy3 | 9999 |
| policy3 | 1234 |
| policy3 | 5555 |
| policy4 | 9999 |
| policy4 | 9999 |

Hello, I am trying to figure out how to take the above table and display the bottom table

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| policy1 | 9999 | red |
| policy2 | 9999 | red |
| policy3 | 9999 | blue |
| policy3 | 1234 | blue |
| policy3 | 5555 | blue |
| policy4 | 9999 | red |
| policy4 | 9999 | red |

Basically I need column C's output to read red if the ONLY value in column B is '9999'.

If column A has numerous values in column B such as policy3, then column C should read blue EVEN if one of the values is '9999'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am just getting stuck using this

SELECT DISTINCT column A,

COUNT(DISTINCT column B)

Comment: If there was a second record for `policy1` that was `9999` would `Column C` still be `red`?

Comment: yes that is correct JNevill

Comment: I updated the sample data to include an example of the clarification from the earlier comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using window functions (which is supported by most RDBMSs):

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, 
    CASE WHEN MIN(ColumnB) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA) = 9999 THEN 'red' else 'blue' END as ColumnC
FROM yourtable
```

This window function is getting the `min(ColumnB)` value for the group of records that share the same `ColumnA` (the "partition"). If that value is `9999` then every record for that `ColumnA` value must be `9999` and so it can be set to `red`.

Note, this will fail if `ColumnB` can have values greater than `9999` since we are using `MIN()` for the logic.

---

If there are values over `9999`, then we can do the following:

```
SELECT tab.ColumnA, tab.ColumnB, 
    CASE WHEN distinctColBCount = 1 AND tab.ColumnB = 9999 THEN 'red' ELSE 'blue' END as ColumnC
FROM yourtable tab
    INNER JOIN 
        (
           SELECT ColumnA, 
               COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnB) as distinctColBCount
           FROM yourtable
           GROUP BY ColumnA
        ) countTab
        ON tab.ColumnA = countTab.columnA
```

Since we can't, in most RDBMSs, do a `COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnB) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA)` a subquery can be used to derive the distinct count. Then we just test if the distinct count is `1` and the current record is `9999` then it must be that only `9999` values are present in the records for this `columnA`.

Comment: What if there are values greater than 9999? there are about 5K rows in my dataset that have a value greater than "9999"

Comment: Bummer man. Just a moment or 30, I'll try to update for that.

Comment: Wow man you are a wizard this worked great! I was on the right track in my own attempts as i knew i needed COUNT distinct in a subquery but wasnt sure how to write it out. I owe you big time you are a serious legend!

Comment: Take a look at Stu's answer as well. I believe it will work the same as the second option with less table scan. I'm not 100% sure if the CASE expression inside the window function will work on every RDBMS, but it likely would.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do the following comparison of counts

```
select *,
    case when 
        Count(*) over(partition by ColumnA)
        = Count(case when ColumnB = 9999 then 1  end) over(partition by ColumnA)
    then 'red' else 'blue' end ColumnC
from t;
```